# Recibe FM radio Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, internet-radio

I am trying to receive fm radio on ubuntu via an dvb-t usb stick. This is [this stick](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/USB2-0-DAB-FM-DVB-T-RTL2832-R820T-SDR-RTL-SDR-Dongle-Stick-Digital-TV-Tuner/32267130430.html). I received a cd with the drivers. But these are for windows and work well. I already installed v4l and tried a lot of different radio applications. But none on them works. I can't find a good driver because it is a not a good known brand.

Does anyone know how i can recieve FM radio on Ubuntu?

**EDIT**

Output of `dmesg | grep DVB`:

```
[   49.692900] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'Astrometa DVB-T2' in warm state
[   49.766190] DVB: registering new adapter (Astrometa DVB-T2)
[   49.823863] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Realtek RTL2832 (DVB-T))...
[   49.823936] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 1 (Panasonic MN88473)...
[   49.915043] input: Astrometa DVB-T2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/rc/rc0/input14
[   49.915151] rc rc0: Astrometa DVB-T2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/rc/rc0
[   49.925960] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 'Astrometa DVB-T2' successfully initialized and connected
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c55 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c040 Logitech, Inc. Corded Tilt-Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 15f4:0131 HanfTek 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output `tail -f /var/log/messages`: This file doesn't exist.

Output `tail -f /var/log/syslog`:

```
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.389943] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.585049] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=15f4, idProduct=0131
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.585053] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.585055] usb 1-1: Product: dvbt2
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.585057] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: astrometadvbt2
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.592166] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'Astrometa DVB-T2' in warm state
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.665828] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.665840] DVB: registering new adapter (Astrometa DVB-T2)
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.669939] i2c i2c-7: Added multiplexed i2c bus 8
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.669944] rtl2832 7-0010: Realtek RTL2832 successfully attached
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.674942] mn88473 7-0018: Panasonic MN88473 successfully attached
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.674950] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Realtek RTL2832 (DVB-T))...
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.674997] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 1 (Panasonic MN88473)...
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.675046] r820t 8-003a: creating new instance
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.686812] r820t 8-003a: Rafael Micro r820t successfully identified
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.686822] r820t 8-003a: attaching existing instance
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.693702] r820t 8-003a: Rafael Micro r820t successfully identified
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.695599] videobuf2_memops: Unknown symbol put_vaddr_frames (err 0)
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.695622] videobuf2_memops: Unknown symbol get_vaddr_frames (err 0)
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.695633] videobuf2_memops: Unknown symbol frame_vector_destroy (err 0)
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.695642] videobuf2_memops: Unknown symbol frame_vector_create (err 0)
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.713892] Registered IR keymap rc-empty
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.713972] input: Astrometa DVB-T2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/rc/rc0/input23
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.714055] rc rc0: Astrometa DVB-T2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/rc/rc0
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.714134] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (dvb_usb_rtl28xxu) registered at minor = 0
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.714138] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: schedule remote query interval to 200 msecs
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc kernel: [ 6684.722755] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 'Astrometa DVB-T2' successfully initialized and connected
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Dec 17 15:28:36 jw-pc mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 12 was not an MTP device
Dec 17 15:28:37 jw-pc kernel: [ 6685.555746] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 12
Dec 17 15:28:37 jw-pc kernel: [ 6685.592369] r820t 8-003a: destroying instance
Dec 17 15:28:37 jw-pc kernel: [ 6685.593642] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 'Astrometa DVB-T2' successfully deinitialized and disconnected
```

Output `lsusb -vvd 15f4:0131`:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 15f4:0131 HanfTek 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x15f4 HanfTek
  idProduct          0x0131 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 astrometadvbt2
  iProduct                2 dvbt2
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 USB2.0-Bulk&Iso
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              5 Bulk-In, Interface
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              5 Bulk-In, Interface
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      2
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Ouput `ls /lib/firmware`:

```
3.16.0-55-generic                dvb-fe-tda10046.fw             ipw2100-1.3-i.fw         macxvi200.bin                  s2250.fw
3.16.0-56-generic                dvb-fe-tda10048-1.0.fw         ipw2100-1.3-p.fw         macxvi.cfg                     s2250_loader.fw
3.19.0-33-generic                dvb-fe-xc4000-1.4.1.fw         ipw2200-bss.fw           Makefile                       s5p-mfc
3.19.0-37-generic                dvb-fe-xc5000-1.6.114.fw       ipw2200-ibss.fw          matrox                         sb16
3.19.0-39-generic                dvb-fe-xc5000c-4.1.30.7.fw     ipw2200-sniffer.fw       moxa                           scripts
3com                             dvb-ttpci-01.fw                isci                     mrvl                           sdd_sagrad_1091_1098.bin
acenic                           dvb-ttpci-01.fw-261a           isl3877                  mt7650.bin                     slicoss
adaptec                          dvb-ttpci-01.fw-261b           isl3886pci               mts_cdma.fw                    sms1xxx-hcw-55xxx-dvbt-02.fw
advansys                         dvb-ttpci-01.fw-261c           isl3886usb               mts_edge.fw                    sms1xxx-hcw-55xxx-isdbt-02.fw
agere_ap_fw.bin                  dvb-ttpci-01.fw-261d           isl3887usb               mts_gsm.fw                     sms1xxx-nova-a-dvbt-01.fw
agere_sta_fw.bin                 dvb-ttpci-01.fw-261f           isl3890                  mts_mt9234mu.fw                sms1xxx-nova-b-dvbt-01.fw
ar3k                             dvb-ttpci-01.fw-2622           iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode     mts_mt9234zba.fw               sms1xxx-stellar-dvbt-01.fw
ar5523.bin                       dvb-ttusb-dec-2000t.fw         iwlwifi-100-5.ucode      mwl8k                          sun
asihpi                           dvb-ttusb-dec-2540t.fw         iwlwifi-105-6.ucode      myri10ge_eth_big_z8e.dat       tehuti
ath10k                           dvb-ttusb-dec-3000s.fw         iwlwifi-135-6.ucode      myri10ge_ethp_big_z8e.dat      ti_3410.fw
ath3k-1.fw                       dvb-usb-af9015.fw              iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode     myri10ge_ethp_z8e.dat          ti_5052.fw
ath6k                            dvb-usb-avertv-a800-02.fw      iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode     myri10ge_eth_z8e.dat           ti-connectivity
atmel_at76c504_2958.bin          dvb-usb-bluebird-01.fw         iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode    myri10ge_rss_eth_big_z8e.dat   tigon
atmel_at76c504a_2958.bin         dvb-usb-dib0700-1.10.fw        iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode    myri10ge_rss_ethp_big_z8e.dat  tlg2300_firmware.bin
atmsar11.fw                      dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw        iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode    myri10ge_rss_ethp_z8e.dat      ttusb-budget
av7110                           dvb-usb-dibusb-5.0.0.11.fw     iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode     myri10ge_rss_eth_z8e.dat       ueagle-atm
bcm2033-fw.bin                   dvb-usb-dibusb-6.0.0.8.fw      iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode     ngene_15.fw                    usbdux
bcm2033-md.hex                   dvb-usb-dtt200u-01.fw          iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode     ngene_17.fw                    usbduxfast_firmware.bin
bcm70012fw.bin                   dvb-usb-it9135-01.fw           iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode     ngene_18.fw                    usbdux_firmware.bin
bcm70015fw.bin                   dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw           iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode     NPE-B                          usbduxsigma_firmware.bin
bnx2x                            dvb-usb-terratec-h5-drxk.fw    iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode     NPE-C                          v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw
brcm                             dvb-usb-terratec-h7-az6007.fw  iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode     ositech                        v4l-cx23418-apu.fw
carl9170-1.fw                    dvb-usb-terratec-h7-drxk.fw    iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode     phanfw.bin                     v4l-cx23418-cpu.fw
carl9170fw                       dvb-usb-tvwalkert.fw           iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode  qat_895xcc.bin                 v4l-cx23418-dig.fw
cbfw-3.2.1.1.bin                 dvb-usb-umt-010-02.fw          iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode  qca                            v4l-cx2341x-dec.fw
cbfw-3.2.3.0.bin                 dvb-usb-vp702x-01.fw           iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode  ql2100_fw.bin                  v4l-cx2341x-enc.fw
cis                              dvb-usb-vp7045-01.fw           iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode     ql2200_fw.bin                  v4l-cx2341x-init.mpg
configure                        dvb-usb-wt220u-01.fw           iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode    ql2300_fw.bin                  v4l-cx23885-avcore-01.fw
cpia2                            dvb-usb-wt220u-02.fw           iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode    ql2322_fw.bin                  v4l-cx23885-enc-broken.fw
ct2fw-3.2.1.1.bin                dvb-usb-wt220u-fc03.fw         iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode    ql2400_fw.bin                  v4l-cx25840.fw
ct2fw-3.2.3.0.bin                dvb-usb-wt220u-zl0353-01.fw    iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode     ql2500_fw.bin                  v4l-pvrusb2-24xxx-01.fw
ctefx.bin                        ea                             iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode     r128                           v4l-pvrusb2-29xxx-01.fw
ctfw-3.2.1.1.bin                 edgeport                       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode     r8a779x_usb3_v1.dlmem          vicam
ctfw-3.2.3.0.bin                 emi26                          iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode    radeon                         vntwusb.fw
ctspeq.bin                       emi62                          iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode    README                         vxge
cxgb3                            ene-ub6250                     iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode    rp2.fw                         WHENCE.ubuntu
cxgb4                            ess                            iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode     rsi_91x.fw                     whiteheat.fw
dsp56k                           f2255usb.bin                   iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode     rt2561.bin                     whiteheat_loader.fw
dvb-cx18-mpc718-mt352.fw         go7007                         iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode   rt2561s.bin                    wsm_22.bin
dvb-dibusb-5.0.0.11.fw           GPL-3                          iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode   rt2661.bin                     xc3028-v27.fw
dvb-fe-bcm3510-01.fw             hp                             iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode   rt2860.bin                     yam
dvb-fe-cx24116.fw                htc_7010.fw                    iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode   rt2870.bin                     yamaha
dvb-fe-drxj-mc-1.0.8.fw          htc_9271.fw                    kaweth                   rt3070.bin                     zd1201-ap.fw
dvb-fe-drxj-mc-vsb-1.0.8.fw      i2400m-fw-usb-1.4.sbcf         keyspan                  rt3090.bin                     zd1201.fw
dvb-fe-drxj-mc-vsb-qam-1.0.8.fw  i2400m-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf         keyspan_pda              rt3290.bin                     zd1211
dvb-fe-nxt2004.fw                i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf          korg                     rt73.bin
dvb-fe-or51132-qam.fw            i915                           lbtf_usb.bin             RTL8192E
dvb-fe-or51132-vsb.fw            intel                          lgs8g75.fw               rtl_nic
dvb-fe-or51211.fw                ipw2100-1.3.fw                 libertas                 rtlwifi
```

Comment: Maybe you might find some information about the drivers here http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/RealTek_RTL2832U#Drivers

Comment: Have you tried gqrx? Also are you sure that Ubuntu doesn't detect your stick?(lsusb)

Comment: please post a *ls /lib/firmware*

Answer (score 2):

Install the software:

```
sudo apt-get install rtl-sdr gqrx-sdr
```

Insert the device. At the terminal, do:

```
gqrx
```

Select a frequency that is known to be a working FM station; 90.7000 Mhz, for example. Click the 'Start DSP Processing' button at the upper left.

Enjoy.

I used this method and an RTL28xx device to listen to FM yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If your v4l card is installed correctly try this:

```
sudo apt-get install gnomeradio
```

if not thry this

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libdigest-sha-perl patchutils libproc-processtable-perl git-core
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

then got to multiverse and

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

then we fetch the source code from git

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
```

go to folder ~/media_build/ and start the build script

```
./build
sudo make install
```

check it with

```
dmesg | grep -i dvb
```

The bad news is that each time you will upgrade your kernel you need to delete the media_build folder and start again by downloading the propper

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
```

have fun

**UPDATE** 
Lets edit here.
please post the output of `dmesg | grep DVB`
and after it the output of `lsusb` 
and plug it and plug it out and post what appears in `tail -f /var/log/messages`

post the result here.

Comment: I did all this but it still doesn't work. Ubuntu still cant find device

Comment: read my update above and do it and post the result

Comment: I updated my question with the outputs.

Comment: @eichertc I believe you want `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

Comment: OKay gimme tail -f /var/log/syslog but only the rows that appear when you plug in and off the USB dongle

Comment: I can see its a Astrometa DVB-T2

Comment: @eichertc Thats right it is the the Astrometa DVB-T2 from this page http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T2_USB_Devices

Comment: Great Its that Hanfteck, Now gimme this `lsusb -vvd 15f4:0131` it should be a long output , add it to your post

Comment: And do not forget the output of the firmware folder to see what you have there `ls /lib/firmware`

Comment: @eichertc I updated the question with the ouputs.

Comment: I think it's not bad to write a email to support@astrometa.com.tw and ask them how they feel :)))

Comment: what kernel do you have? is it a 3.2.+ ? Check it with `uname -a`

Comment: @eichertc **Linux jw-pc 3.19.0-39-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 2 10:00:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

      I asked the vendor on aliexpress for the drivers but his awners was "Yes."

Comment: You do not have the firmware. in the firmware folder should be something like AMDVBT2. I can't see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33106/discussion-between-eichertc-and-user2735398).